# Delete/hide tr if td contains span id

Tags: jquery

```
<tr class="odd" height="30">
  <td colspan="4">
    <span id="ctl00_innerContentPlaceHolder_PartnerAddressControl1_stbxCareOf" style="display:inline-block;width:150px;">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Hello,

I want to hide or delete `<tr>` if `<td>` contains `<span>` with id `ctl00_innerContentPlaceHolder_PartnerAddressControl1_stbxCareOf`

Please guide me how it can be achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element with that `id` and then hide it's parent `tr`. Try this:

```
$('#ctl00_innerContentPlaceHolder_PartnerAddressControl1_stbxCareOf').closest('tr').hide();
```

Note however that this `id` is automatically generated by ASP.Net and may change at a later time. In this case, you would need to identify the element by a combination of a class and it's parent's identifiers, or by using the `ClientID` property of the .Net control.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has()` selector along with `.hide()` or else `.remove()` for hiding or removing the `tr`:

```
    $('tr:has(#ctl00_innerContentPlaceHolder_PartnerAddressControl1_stbxCareOf)').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**:has()**](https://www.google.com/url?url=https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwius5v79ZPHAhVlmtsKHZzFBA0&sig2=QrK7sbftsP3lQAXeLR6DyQ&usg=AFQjCNHVrzH4QTCEp7NFBEeqJVUxIzFN0w)

```
$('tr:has(#ctl00_innerContentPlaceHolder_PartnerAddressControl1_stbxCareOf)').remove();
```